# How to make attributes selection independent from each other in frontend?

Tags: magento

i need help with magento.
I have tried several ways but could not find it.
Lets say i have a product with 2 different attributes like Color and Size.
When i add those attributes to a product and than check the frontend, i first need to choose one attribute in order to make the other attribute selectable.
Isn´t it possible to make alltibutes independent from each other selectable, so the user can choose which attribute he likes to select first.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge, it is not possible to make attributes independent of each other, because magento manages associated products according to options selected.

But you can decide which option should control other by drag attributes up or down in admin for each product.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use attributes but can simply create custom options on the configurable product level. These custom options will be displayed for every linked simple product and your customers can select each of those independently.

Be careful to create these options on the configurable product level. If you chose to create them on the simple product level you won't be able to link the products anymore unless you set the custom options to "not required".
(Keep in mind I am using Magento version 1.6.2, so this might be different for newer versions)

Hope that helped.